# Is there a way that I present my idea to Apple

Tags: applications

I have an idea for a new app that can able to have a billion-dollar profit; but I need a good support to present this product as internationally and exclusively in a reputable company. I think this idea has not been presented yet, while it is simple, but yet innovative.
This is about a fun application which can be attracting attention of a lot of people who interested to chance and lotteries, and also are enthusiast of Apple products.
Unfortunately I live in Iran, and there is no any Apple representative here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Apple will not listen to any app ideas.  If you believe you have a good idea, hire a developer and create the app yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Apple really isn't interested:

> Apple or any of its employees do not accept or consider unsolicited ideas, including ideas for new advertising campaigns, new promotions, new or improved products or technologies, product enhancements, processes, materials, marketing plans or new product names. Please do not submit any unsolicited ideas, original creative artwork, suggestions or other works (“submissions”) in any form to Apple or any of its employees.

http://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/policies/ideas.html